# Android layout performance with styled text

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Im having a problem deciding on which route to go when it comes to the performance of layouts in Android. I have quite a huge layout that needs to be populated with text from an API. Now the problem is that captions have to be in **bold**. To simplify it looks something like this.

**Caption 1:** Lorem ipsum...
**Caption 2:** Lorem ipsum...
**Caption 3:** Lorem ipsum...
etc..

As I see it I have 2 choices. Either I go for 2 views to accomplish this, something like

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Caption 1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum..." />

         </LinearLayout>
```

or I go for one TextView and use

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>Caption 1</b> Lorem ipsum")
```

I'm wondering of anyone has any numbers on performance on the two approaches. Considering the large view I have to display it would be great to know. It feels like option 2 is better but I dont have have any evidence of that and I don't really have time to test them both.

Cheers!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have some control over the API as well so I can embed HTML in the API and send back strings in the form of

```
"<b>Caption</b> Lorem ipsum...".
```

Judging from the two initial answers the first approach is out the window.

Comment: You could modify the API, but what if in the future you want it to be Italic instead of Bold? Then you have to go modify the API again. What if some responses need to be different than others based on information gathered at runtime? I would suggest it's safer and cleaner to handle it in code if there's a known pattern "Caption ():" that you need to style.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for faster performance, I would advice you to use `SpannableStringBuilder` instead of `Html.fromHtml`.

Html.fromHtml actually uses `SpannableStringBuilder` in it's implementation, but given, that fromHtml also takes time to actually parse your html string (and add to this the time YOU need to wrap text in html tags) it'll perform slower than `SpannableStringBuilder`

And any of those variants will be faster than populating and maintaining views from xmls

P.S. I even have a little article about `SpannableStringBuilder` to get you started: http://illusionsandroid.blogspot.com/2011/05/modifying-coloring-scaling-part-of-text.html

Comment: Yes, I did have a look at that too, but with all the varying lengths of everything from the API it makes me somewhat hesitant to use since I have to specify every range. edit: I also have (some) control over the API so I can have it send back properly formed strings with the HTML already embedded

Answer (score 0):

I <3 Regex, so I like a method like this:

```
String myCaption = "Caption 1: Lorem Ipsum...";
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

//Set a Regex pattern to find instances of "Caption X:" 
//where X is any integer.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Caption [0-9]+:");

//Get a matcher for the caption string and find the first instance
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myCaption);
matcher.find();

//These are the start and ending indexes of the discovered pattern
int startIndex = matcher.start();
int endIndex = matcher.end();

//Sets a BOLD span on the
Spannable textSpan = new Spannable(myCaption);
textSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 
    startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//Set this Spannable as the TextView text
tv.setText(textSpan);
```

I haven't tested this, but the idea should get you going even if this doesn't work as it is verbatim. Basically, use a Regex to find the "Caption X:" part of the string, get the start and end indexes, and set a Bold span on that particular section of text.